# Move files into new folder while using another folder as the structure

Tags: powershell, directory, robocopy

Here is my situation :

I have a bunch of folders containing images, some folders have sub-folders, and some don't:

> ```
> .
> └── folder0
>     ├── folder1
>     │   └── imageA.png
>     ├── folder2
>     │   ├── imageB.png
>     │   ├── imageC.png
>     │   └── imageD.png
>     └── folder3
>         └── folder4
>             └── imageE.png
> ```

Now I want to upscale these images using some kind of software, so I input all the images into the software, and it dumps everything into a "dump" folder somewhere else.

> ```
> .
> └── dump-folder
>     ├── imageA-upscaled.png
>     ├── imageB-upscaled.png
>     ├── imageC-upscaled.png
>     ├── imageD-upscaled.png
>     └── imageE-upscaled.png
> ```

My question is : How can I use Powershell to create a new folder called "folder1-upscaled" and **move the upscaled images in that folder while maintaining the original structure of "*folder1*"**

As I have a new folder containing all the subfolders as "**folder0**" like such:

> ```
> .
> └── folder0-upscaled
>     ├── folder1
>     ├── folder2
>     └── folder3
>         └── folder4
> ```

I need to move the files from **dump-folder** to **folder0-upscaled** while using the structure of **folder0** as a template for where the files should go in the subfolders.

Comment: Use robocopy. ;-)

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path '.\Folder1\*' -Destination '.\Folder1-upscaled' -Recurse -Force`.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I came up with this :

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\test\folder0" -Recurse -File


foreach ($file in $files) {
    $destination = "G:\test\folder0-upscaled" + $file.DirectoryName.Substring("G:\test\folder0".Length)
    $fileUpscaledPath = Join-Path "G:\test\dump" $file.Name
    Move-Item -Path $fileUpscaledPath -Destination $destination -force
}
```

This successfully copies the NEW (upscaled) images to the correct folders corresponding to the structure of **folder0**

Here is a version where the upscaled images are of a different file extension :

```
# Define the extension of the upscaled images
$extension = ".tiff"

# Get the list of files in "folder0" and its subfolders
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\test\folder0" -Recurse -File

# Loop through the files
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $destination = "G:\test\folder0-upscaled" + $file.DirectoryName.Substring("G:\test\folder0".Length)
    $fileUpscaledPath = Join-Path "G:\test\dump" ($file.Name -replace $file.Extension, $extension)
    Move-Item -Path $fileUpscaledPath -Destination $destination -force
}
```